# Why is my attempt to clone an object not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to clone the object props.messages.serverError; I tried the following three methods individually:

```
 1. let serverError= {...props.messages.serverError};
 2. let serverError = Object.assign({}, props.messages.serverError);
 3. let serverError= JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(props.messages.serverError}));
```

After cloning the object I set the original object to null then log the cloned object a as follows:

```
props.messages.serverError = null;
console.log('serverError', serverError)
```

serverError is also null instead of the original value even though it is now supposed to occupy a memory address different from the original object due to the cloning.

Comment: because 1 and 2 those are not deep clones. Unclear how 3 would have the same problem. Maybe you should be showing the actual code so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: @espascarello the 3rd method using Json.parse is a deep clone, but even with the shallow clones it should be creating a new memory address as to not modify the original object

Comment: It isn't modifying the original object.  The only way that console log could emit null is if the input object was null before cloning.

Comment: There's also a syntax error on 3. The closing bracket after `props.messages.serverError` should be removed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the most efficient way to deep clone an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript)

Comment: @koque it might be helpful to have a minimal, complete, and reproducible example that replicates the problem. Those 3 clones should work fine

Comment: @Smarticles101 Protip:  you can use `[mre]` to generate a link to [mre].

Comment: I double-cloned the object and it seemed to work: The answer is provided below.

Comment: @koque I think you need to update the question with a reproduceable example, otherwise this question is just noise.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprise how you can set the value for `props`? `Props` are read-only. You are changing that value directly without any interaction of `react` maybe that's why it is changing the actual value. You can try something like this.

```js
let props = {
  messages: {
    serverError: 404
  }
}

let serverError = { ...props.messages };
console.log("Initial Value", serverError.serverError);

props.messages.serverError = 500;
console.log("After Update: (Props)", props.messages.serverError);
console.log("After Update:", serverError.serverError);
```

Answer (score -1):

I double-cloned the object and it seemed to work:

```
let originalError = {...props.messages.serverError};
let serverError = {...originalError};
originalError = null;
props.messages.serverError = null;
console.log('serverError', serverError)
```

Here serverError now has the original value.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in your question's title.  "Why doesn't this work as expected?"